# How to prevent Back Button from hiding my keyboard in my react native app?

Tags: react-native, keyboard, back

So I have a simple input, When I focus on it, the keybord pops up, but I want that my keybord hide only if If click on ok, or Enter, But what I see is that when I click the 'BACK' button of my phone, the keyboard disappear, and I don't want that, or at least I want to detect it in my component.

This is how I handle the back click in my app ! Knowing that I have three screens in my app, authentication screen ( LOGIN ), main screen ( MAIN ) , and route screen ( ROUTE ).

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

import { prevScreen } from '../../helpers/NavigationService';
import { SCREENKEYS } from '../../business/constants';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const useBackAction = screen => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const backAction = () => {
      if (screen === SCREENKEYS.LOGIN) BackHandler.exitApp();
      else if (screen === SCREENKEYS.MAIN) return true;
      else prevScreen();

      return true;
    };

    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backAction);

    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, [screen]);
};

export default useBackAction;
```

Is there something I have to add to prevent the back click from hiding mu keybord view ?

Comment: No one has an idea ?